# Manipulating Data.Frames

Tags: r

I have different data.frame objects with two columns. These data.frame objects are called Experiment1, Experiment2, Experiment3 ... Experiment{n}

`> Experiment1
  Name Statistic
1    a    -1.050
2    b     0.058
3    c     0.489
4    d     1.153
5    e     0.736
6    f    -1.155
7    g     0.186`

`> Experiment2
  Name Statistic
1    a     0.266
2    b     0.067
3    c    -0.385
4    d     0.068
5    e     1.563
6    f     0.745
7    g     1.671`

`> Experiment3
  Name Statistic
1    a     0.004
2    b    -2.074
3    c     0.746
4    d     0.207
5    e     0.700
6    f     0.158
7    g     0.067`

`> Experiment4
  Name Statistic
1    a     0.255
2    b    -0.542
3    c     0.477
4    d     1.552
5    e     0.025
6    f     1.027
7    g     0.326`

`> Experiment5
  Name Statistic
1    a     1.817
2    b     0.147
3    c     0.052
4    d     0.194
5    e    -0.137
6    f     2.321
7    g    -0.939`

`> Experiment6
  Name Statistic
1    a     1.817
2    b     0.147
3    c     0.052
4    d     0.194
5    e    -0.137
6    f     2.321
7    g    -0.939`

`> ExperimentalDesign$metabolite
 [1] "butyrate"     "h2s"          "hippurate"    "acetate"      "propionate"   "butyrate_2"  [7] "h2s_2"        "hippurate_2"  "acetate_2"    "propionate_2"`

I have different data.frame objects with three columns. These data.frame objects are called Experiment1, Experiment2, Experiment3 ... Experiment{n} (where n is NumberTubes divided by NumberParameters).

Now I want to merge from each data.frame object the .$Statistic column in a table (3 statistic columns per output..)
tab_1 <- cbind(Experiment1, Experiment2$Statistic, Experiment3$Statistic). Also, take the metabolite from ExperimentalDesign$metabolite in order. e.g. Table_3 would get  hippurate.

1. NumberRepeats <- 3   (Table_1 = merge Experiment_1,
   Experiment_2$Statistic, Experiment_3$Statistic , Table_2 = merge
   Experiment_4, Experiment_5$Statistic, Experiment_6$Statistic, etc.)
2. Experiment_n <- 17     (e.g. Experiment_1, Experiment_2, etc..)
3. skipTube <- c(11)         (skip Experiment_11)

Desired outputs:

Table_1:

  `Experiment1 Experiment2 Experiment3   metabolite
a -1.050  0.266  0.004  butyrate
b  0.058  0.067 -2.074  butyrate
c  0.489 -0.385  0.746  butyrate
d  1.153  0.068  0.207  butyrate
e  0.736  1.563  0.700  butyrate
f -1.155  0.745  0.158  butyrate
g  0.186  1.671  0.067  butyrate`

Table_2

`Experiment4 Experiment5 Experiment6  metabolite
a 0.255  1.817 -0.827   h2s
b -0.542  0.147  0.219  h2s
c  0.477  0.052  1.561  h2s
d  1.552  0.194  1.493  h2s
e  0.025 -0.137  0.063  h2s
f  1.027  2.321  0.844  h2s
g  0.326 -0.939 -0.373  h2s`

TRIED SO FAR:

With this you merge on column of different dataframe objects to one table. You can control the number of column by the `NumberRepeats` variable. All table which are stored in a list have same number of data columns like the
`NumberRepeats` variable except the last table...

```
# created test data
for(i in 1:17){
  Name <- letters[1:7]
  Statistic <- round(rnorm(7), 3)
  assign(paste0("Experiment",i), data.frame(Name, Statistic))
}    

# set some parameters
NumberRepeats <- 3
Experiment_n <- 17
skipTube <- c(11)
```

# lets go

```
out <- list()
list_index <- 1
counter <- 1
while(counter < Experiment_n) {

  tab <- NULL
  nam <- NULL
  while((is.null(tab) || ncol(tab) < NumberRepeats) & Experiment_n >= counter){
    if(!any(counter == skipTube)){
      tab <- cbind(tab, get(paste0("Experiment", counter))$Statistic)
      # tab <- as.data.frame(tab)
      nam <- c(nam,paste0("Experiment", counter))
    }
    counter <- counter + 1  
  }
  colnames(tab) <- nam
  rownames(tab) <- as.matrix(Experiment1$Name)

  out[[list_index]] <- tab
  assign(paste0('table_', list_index), tab)

  list_index <- list_index + 1  
}
out
```

Output from above code:

`Experiment1 Experiment2 Experiment3 
a       0.136       0.260      -1.089

b       0.946      -1.165      -0.599

c      -0.462      -1.445       0.044

d      -1.936      -0.391       0.622

e       0.537      -0.502       1.192

f       0.259       0.096      -1.873

g       1.352       0.049      -0.644`

Desired output from the above code:

`Experiment1 Experiment2 Experiment3   metabolite
a -1.050  0.266  0.004  butyrate
b  0.058  0.067 -2.074  butyrate
c  0.489 -0.385  0.746  butyrate
d  1.153  0.068  0.207  butyrate
e  0.736  1.563  0.700  butyrate
f -1.155  0.745  0.158  butyrate
g  0.186  1.671  0.067  butyrate`

Comment: It is helpful if you can provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), with both a sample of your data and code for what what you've tried so far.

Comment: You said three columns but only show two, what else is there? You referenced `NumberParameters` but never demonstrate its use; is this supposed to be `NumberRepeats`? I strongly recommend for using a [list of dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207) instead of accessing individual frames with `assign`, it is usually much easier, more efficient, and much more robust.

Comment: I have updated the question to answer this

Comment: What if the number of experiments are not perfectly divisible by 3?

Comment: then the final table should be 1 or 2, not 3

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work but this also quite manual:

```
table1 = Reduce(function(x,y){cbind(x,y)},
list(Experiment1$Statistic,Experiment2$Statistic,
Experiment3$Statistic,ExperimentalDesign$metabolite[1]))

table2 = Reduce(function(x,y){cbind(x,y)},
list(Experiment4$Statistic,Experiment5$Statistic,
Experiment6$Statistic,ExperimentalDesign$metabolite[2]))
```

**EDIT**: A more robust solution:

First create a list of all the experiment data.frames named `ldf`:

```
ldf = list(Experiment1,Experiment2,Experiment3,...,Experimentn)
```

And then:

```
lapply(1:ceiling(length(ldf)/3),
   function(t,l,df){ 
     if(t==ceiling(length(l)/3)){
       ind = ((3*t)-2):(3*t-(length(l)%%3))
     }else{
       ind = ((3*t)-2):(3*t)
     };
    cbind(Reduce(function(x,y){cbind(x,y)},lapply(l[ind],'[[','Statistic')),
    df$metabolite[t])
    },
ldf,ExperimentalDesign)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution should do what you want in case you want to aggregate every 3 tables.

```
library(reshape)

for(i in 1:17){
  Name <- letters[1:7]
  Statistic <- round(rnorm(7), 3)
  ExperimentName <- rep(paste0("Experiment",i), 7)
  assign(paste0("Experiment",i), data.frame(ExperimentName, Name, Statistic, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) )
}    

# set some parameters
NumberRepeats <- 5
Experiment_n <- 17
skipTube <- c(3,7,11)

# Create dummy list for the metabolites
metabolites <- c("met1", "met2", "met3", "met4", "met5")

for (iteration in c(1:Experiment_n)){
  if (iteration %% 3 == 0){
    temp_df <- rbind(get(paste0("Experiment", iteration - 2)), get(paste0("Experiment", iteration - 1)), get(paste0("Experiment", iteration)))
    print(temp_df)
    temp_df <- melt(data = temp_df)
    aggregates <- dcast(data = temp_df, formula = Name ~ ExperimentName, value.var = "value")
    aggregates$metabolite <- metabolites[iteration/3]
    print(aggregates)
  }
}
```